# 3DMax batch render 100 tasks

Tags: batch-processing, 3dsmax

I have 25 models, each with a nr of frames between 1 and 32 frames.
There are 4 cameras and I am to render 4 x 25 tasks in total.

Can't set up 100 tasks in Batch Render dialog box because it would take weeks.

I made a bat file programmatically to render things, but It loads and closes the .max file for each task, and due to the high size of the max file, it takes a minute. This is more than the render itself.

How can I make the bat file use the already opened 3d max and not close/open it each time? Or how to programmatically generate instructions for those 100 tasks and not open/close the max file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use maxscript for it.
You need a script that opens the file, set's the cameras, renders out from each camera, close the file and go to the next one - without closing 3dsmax.

if you break it down into each step then there are examples for each task in the maxscript manual.

Load maxfile:
http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-624D3D05-B15D-4A97-9F15-DA35CDB0DDD2.htm#SECTION_2D91EF0731CE4C5889583719F815BDAA

Set viewport camera:
http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-8AA71F9E-F4F0-4437-A44E-9683619E89DE.htm,topicNumber=d30e683762

render from camera:
http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-9175301C-13E6-488B-ABA6-D27CD804B205.htm,topicNumber=d30e676998

Comment: For other people who search for this and come here, please post the links to the 3ds max manual for the steps.

Comment: Added links to these steps now. Thanks for reminder.

Comment: Going to add that one can just put the code in an outside .ms file and run it / edit it directly in the 3d max instance.